# Passing params through a Func<>

Tags: c#, delegates, func

I use delegates with lambda expressions instead of methods with just one line of code like:

```
Func<int, int, int> Add = (x, y) => x + y;
int Result = Add(1, 2); // 3
```

Now I have the problem that I need a unknown number of parameters. Is there a was to solve it like this:

```
 Func<string, params string[], string> MergeFormat = (Look, values) => string.Format(Look, string.Join("-", values));
```

with `params string[]`

the result would be

```
string.Format(func, string.Join("-", v1, v2, v3)); //currently
MergeFormat(func, v1, v2, v3); //new
```

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you're trying to do. I suspect the problem can be solved by using your own delegate, but if you could provide more information it would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`params` isn't part of the type itself, so you can't specify a `Func<string, params string[], string>`. But you could declare your own delegates which are like `Func` but which have a parameter array as the final parameter. For example:

```
using System;

delegate TResult ParamsFunc<T, TResult>(params T[] arg);
delegate TResult ParamsFunc<T1, T2, TResult>(T1 arg1, params T2[] arg2);
delegate TResult ParamsFunc<T1, T2, T3, TResult>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2, params T3[] arg3);
// etc        

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ParamsFunc<string, string, string> func =
            (format, values) => string.Format(format, string.Join("-", values));

        string result = func("Look here: {0}", "a", "b", "c");
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not even legal to mention the `params` keyword in the lambda itself, i.e. changing your arrow to `(string format, params string[] values) => string.Format(format, string.Join("-", values));` will not compile.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Right - and it wouldn't make *sense* for it to be part of the lambda. It makes perfect sense for it to be part of the delegate declaration though.

Comment: I suppose you are rigth. The keyword is translated to a `ParamArrayAttribute` on the parameter. That could be applied to the generated method (into which the lambda is translated), but it would not help much. When invoking `func` (of your code) we do not know what method(s) it holds. However, if I make a lambda with `ref` (I use `(ref int x) => { };`) and another one with `out`, I see that the [`OutAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.outattribute.aspx) is applied on the compiler-generated method.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it this way, but there is a workaround solution that you could use:

If you define your Func this way:

```
Func<string[], string> FuncArray = (listOfStrings) => 
{
    // Here you can work on the listOfStrings, process it... 
    // and finaly you return a string from this method... 
}
```

Then you can later use that FuncArray in other calls this way:

```
public void MyMethod(Func<string[], string> delegateMethod, params string[] listOfString)
{
    if (delegateMethod != null)
    {
        string value = delegateMethod(listOfStrings);
    }

}
```

So you simply define a Func<> that takes an array of strings as a parameter, and then you can call that Func<> from another method which has a "params string[]" parameter.